# Iterate over Array[java.lang.Object] in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have Scala type:

```
Array[java.lang.Object]
```

Tried to iterate over it:

```
for (el <- arrayTest) {
    println("el: " + el)
}
```

Result:

```
el: ["null","string"]
```

How to separate out each element to become:

```
el: "null"
el: "string"
```

Comment: your code actually produces the expected result (two lines starting with `el: `) for the input: `Array[java.lang.Object](null, "string")`.

Comment: @Tzach - I was expecting 2 separate lines (e.g. like in Python). Do you know why is printing only 1 line? How to 'test' each element if is 'null'? Just to compare 'if el==null'?

Comment: As I wrote - your code _does_ produce two separate lines when I run it. Please add your exact _input_ (how this array is created) to the question, because the issue might be there. As for null comparisons, yes, `if (el == null)`  works, although you should also check out using Scala's `Option`, e.g. `Option(el).foreach(println("el: " + _))`.

Comment: Seems like your array contains 1 element which is composed of those 2 elements. Please show how you're populating the array.

Answer (score 2):

If you run this

```
val arrayTest: Array[java.lang.Object] = Array(null, "string")

for (el <- arrayTest) {
  println("el: " + el)
}
```

you get this

```
el: null
el: string
```

So it is definitely iterating through the `Array` as required.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, here is what I tried in scala REPL.

```
scala> val arr:Array[java.lang.Object] = Array("null","string")
arr: Array[Object] = Array(null, string)

scala> for (el <- arr)(println("el: "+el))
el: null
el: string

scala>
```

Answer (score -4):

```
For( type  e : arrayTest)
    println("el: " + e);
```

> "e" it's the object at each position of the array.

Comment: In Scala: `arrayTest.map(e => println("el: " + e))` In my opition it's better to use `map` instead of `for` for only one thing.

Comment: Hmm.. does not print anything (empty).. My example foreach in question prints 1 line for 2 objects (that's how I understand).

Comment: Can you give me your `arrayTest`?

Comment: It looks like this `e` is your object, so you need to use something to get information from it. You have `Array[java.lang.Object]` but you need to know what's this object is. So you can use `for`, `map`, `foreach` to iterate through Array. It's not a problem, but the result  is object so if you have something like `Person(firstName: String, lastName: String)` and an array of that so access to the specific field is `person.firstName` In case that you have `java.lang.Object` you can use `isInstanceOf` to change it to object that you should have.